# Best way of saving edit history in postgresql with Django

Tags: django, postgresql

A lot of times I've had the need to know "who updated what" in my database tables. I've always done this by creating similar tables with extra fields, for instance "updated_by" and "time_updated" which store the user who edited the record and when they did it respectively.

Here's a simple example;

```
CREATE TABLE student
(

    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name varchar(100) PRIMARY KEY,
    last_name varchar(100),

);

CREATE TABLE student_edit_history
(

    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    student_id integer,
    first_name varchar(100) PRIMARY KEY,
    last_name varchar(100),
    updated_by varchar(100),
    time_updated timestamptz,

);
```

Is there a better way of achieving the same in PostgreSQL without creating new tables? Does Django provide a way of saving edit history?

Comment: There are django apps that can do this for you - http://django-auditlog.readthedocs.org/

Comment: The above will still create tables, it will just do it automatically. You might to take a look at [PGAudit](https://www.pgaudit.org/). It records to a log file.